# Django Rendering Radio Button Options with Extra Information from Model

Tags: django, forms, widget, radio-button, models

I have a Location model and an associated form that displays the "location" field as a bunch of radio buttons (using the form queryset to display the values).  There are a small number of locations, but they need to be dynamic.  I'd like to display the location description next to each radio box option so users have a bit more info on the locations.

Pretend this is a list of radio buttons, this is what I'd like it to look like:

<> East  - This location is east.  <> West  - This is the west location!  <> North - This is the north location

I have a model similar to the following:

```
class Location(models.Models):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And a form as such:

```
class LocationForm(forms.Form):
    location = ExtraModelChoiceField(
               widget=RadioSelect(renderer=ExtraHorizRadioRenderer), 
               queryset = models.Locations.objects.filter(active=True))
```

I can't seem to find a good way to render the form so I can display the description along with each select option.  I've done a lot of overriding, but am not having too much luck.

MY ATTEMPT TO SOLVE (BUT NO LUCK YET):

From what I gather, normally if a queryset is provided on the form field, the Django form logic translates that into a choices tupal of tupals.  Each "subtupal" contains an id and label that is displayed when it is rendered.  I'm trying to add a third value to those "subtupals" which would be a description.

I've defined a custom renderer to display my radio buttons horizontally and to pass in my custom choices.

```
class ExtraHorizRadioRenderer(forms.RadioSelect.renderer):
    def render(self):
        return mark_safe(u'\n'.join([u'%s\n' % w for w in self]))

    def __iter__(self):
        for i, choice in enumerate(self.choices):
            yield ExtraRadioInput(self.name, self.value, 
                                  self.attrs.copy(), choice, i)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        choice = self.choices[idx] # Let the IndexError propogate
        return ExtraRadioInput(self.name, self.value, 
                               self.attrs.copy(), choice, idx)
```

I've overridden the Django RadioInput class so I can add the description information that I need to display next to the Radio Buttons.

```
class ExtraRadioInput(forms.widgets.RadioInput):

    def __init__(self, name, value, attrs, choice, index):
        self.name, self.value = name, value
        self.attrs = attrs
        self.choice_value = force_unicode(choice[0])
        self.choice_label = force_unicode(choice[1])
        self.choice_description = force_unicode(choice[2])   # <--- MY ADDITION; FAILS
        self.index = index

    def __unicode__(self):
        if 'id' in self.attrs:
            label_for = ' for="%s_%s"' % (self.attrs['id'], self.index)
        else:
            label_for = ''
        choice_label = conditional_escape(force_unicode(self.choice_label))
        return mark_safe(u'<label%s>%s %s</label>' % (
             label_for, self.tag(), choice_label))

    def tag(self):
        if 'id' in self.attrs:
            self.attrs['id'] = '%s_%s' % (self.attrs['id'], self.index)
        final_attrs = dict(self.attrs, type='radio', name=self.name, 
                      value=self.choice_value)
        if self.is_checked():
            final_attrs['checked'] = 'checked'
        return mark_safe(
           u'<input%s /><span class="description">%s</span>' % \
           (flatatt(final_attrs),self.choice_description ))  # <--- MY ADDTIONS
```

I've also overridden the following two Django classes hoping to pass around my modified choices tupals.

```
class ExtraModelChoiceIterator(forms.models.ModelChoiceIterator  ):    

    def choice(self, obj): 
        if self.field.to_field_name:
            key = obj.serializable_value(self.field.to_field_name)
        else:
            key = obj.pk

        if obj.description:   # <-- MY ADDITIONS
            description = obj.description
        else:
            description = ""
        return (key, self.field.label_from_instance(obj),description)


class ExtraModelChoiceField(forms.models.ModelChoiceField):

    def _get_choices(self):
        if hasattr(self, '_choices'):
            return self._choices
        return ExtraModelChoiceIterator(self)  # <-- Uses MY NEW ITERATOR
```

Using the approach above, I can't seem to be able to pass around my 3-value tupal.  I get a "tuple index out of range" failure (up where I mark FAILURE above) indicating that somehow my tupal does not have the extra value.

Does anyone see a flaw in my logic, or more generally have an approach to displaying a description next to a list of choices using a widget?

Thanks for reading. Any comments are much appreciated.
Joe

Comment: Have you considered just using CSS to do this? It seems a lot easier to me. I feel like Python/Django developers do not need to worry about formatting like this with server side code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I think I have a method to do this.  As always, it appears to be simpler than I was making it before.  Overriding the label_from_instance method on an extended ModelChoiceField seems to allow me to access the model object instance to be able to print out extra information.

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode, force_unicode

class ExtraModelChoiceField(forms.models.ModelChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(
            "<span>%s</span><span class=\"desc\" id=\"desc_%s\">%s</span>" % (
            mart_unicode(obj), obj.id, smart_unicode(obj.description),))


class HorizRadioRenderer(forms.RadioSelect.renderer):
    # for displaying select options horizontally. 
    # https://wikis.utexas.edu/display/~bm6432/Django-Modifying+RadioSelect+Widget+to+have+horizontal+buttons
    def render(self):
        return mark_safe(u'\n'.join([u'%s\n' % w for w in self]))


class LocationForm(forms.Form):
    location = ExtraModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer),
        queryset=models.Location.objects.filter(active=True))
```

If you know of a better approach, I'd be excited to see it.  Otherwise, this will have to do.  Thanks for reading.  Hope this saves someone the frustration I had.

Joe

Answer (score 2):

Did you take a look at this snippet: [RadioSelectWithHelpText](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2146) ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Django doesn't provide a simple way to add extra attributes to form fields. In particular, choice fields values are constrained to be simple strings.

This solution provides a way to provide string-like objects for choice values as well as extra attributes.

Consider a simple model with several choices as values.

```
# models.py
from django import models

_value_choices = ['value#1', 'value#2', 'value#3'] # the literal values for users
# list creates a list rather than generator
# enumerate provides integers for storage
VALUE_CHOICES = list(zip(enumerate(_value_choices)))

class MyModel(models.Model):
    value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=VALUE_CHOICES)
```

We create a `ModelForm` as usual.

```
# forms.py
from django import forms

from . import models

class MyModel(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = ['value']
        widgets = {
            'value': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

Now suppose we have the following template:

```
{# template #}
{% for radio in field %}
<li>
    <div>
        {{ radio.tag }}
        <label for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}">
    </div>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem we now have before us is to expand the template so that each label can have extra text that is associated with the choice.

The solution consists of two parts:
I - use a special class for the choice values which can be coerced to a string;
II - create a deconstruct method on how to convert from the stored value to a full object.

### I: Creating a special class for visible choice values

This is straightforward.

```
class RadioChoice:
    def __init__(self, label, arg1, arg2): # as many as you want
        self.label = label
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def __str__(self): # only the label attribute is official
        return self.label
```

Now rewrite `_value_choices` above to use this class

```
_value_choices = [
    RadioChoice('value#1', 'value_arg1_1', 'value_arg1_2'),
    RadioChoice('value#2', 'value_arg2_1', 'value_arg2_2'),
    RadioChoice('value#3', 'value_arg3_1', 'value_arg3_2'),
]
```

Include the new attributes in your template.

```
{% for radio in field %}
    <li>
        <div>
            {{ radio.tag }}
            <label for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}"><span>{{ radio.choice_label }}</span> <span>{{ radio.choice_label.arg1 }}</span></label>
            <small>{{ radio.choice_label.arg2 }}</small>
        </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Now test to ensure it works as expected.

### II: Add the `deconstruct()` method and run migrations

Once you are sure it works correctly you will need to create a new migration for the change in the models.

```
class RadioChoice:
    def __init__(self, label, arg1, arg2): # as many as you want
        self.label = label
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def __str__(self): # only the label attribute is official
        return self.label

    def deconstruct(self):
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#adding-a-deconstruct-method
        # you must return three arguments: path (to the module from the project root), args and kwargs
        path = "app_name.models.RadioChoice"
        args = (self.label, self.arg1, self.arg2)
        kwargs = dict()
        return path, args, kwargs
```

Finally, run `python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate`.